# The geometric way to view differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Firstly, I have to apologize if my question is very trivial.

My question is about differential forms; what does it mean to say that a differential form on a smooth manifold can be viewed as a smooth section of the exterior power of the cotangent bundle and that this is the geometric way to view it. Does this mean that there is an isomorphism between the space of differential forms on a smooth manifold $M$ and the space of smooth sections of the exterior power of the cotangent bundle $\Gamma(M, \wedge T^*(M))$, if so my thought is that this map associates to a differential form $\alpha \in \mathcal{A}^k(M)$, the smooth section $\tilde{\alpha}$ which is given by
$$(\tilde{\alpha}(m))(v_1,...,v_k):= \alpha_m(v_1,...,v_k),$$
where $m \in M$ and $ v_1,...,v_k$ are tangent vectors in $T_mM$ ?

2. What it means to say that this is the geometric way to view differential forms?

**Edit(Clarification of notations):**   $\mathcal{A}^k(M)$ denotes the space of differential forms on $M$: we say that $\alpha \in \mathcal{A}^k(M)$ if it is a multilinear, antisymmetric function which takes as input $k$ smooth vector fields on $M$,  and outputs a scalar function on $M$.

On the other hand $\Gamma(M, \wedge^kT^*(M)$ denotes the space of smooth sections on the exterior power of the cotangent bundle: We say that $s\in \Gamma(M, \wedge^kT^*(M)$ if $s$ is a smooth map which takes as input an element of  $ m \in M$  and outputs a $k$ multilinear antisymmetric on $s_m :T_mM \times ...\times T_mM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What makes something “geometric”?

Comment: I definitely do not have the answer to this question! (The naive picture that comes to my mind when I heard that something is geometric is that it is related to some concepts that I already know that they are geometric (e.g.: metrics, curvatures , surfaces...),  and these concepts are called "geometric" since they generalize  geometric objetcts in the real life like  shapes and surfaces and volumes).

Comment: Regarding notation and terminology, what is $\mathcal{A}^k(M)$, i.e., what is a "differential form" for the purposes of the question? (Is it the sheaf of sections of the $k$th exterior power of $T^*M$? And part of the question is about an isomorphism with the space of global sections of the $k$th exterior power of $T^*M$...?)

Comment: I don't know for certain why the sections-of-bundles picture is _geometric_, but have always assumed it referred to expressing differential forms (classically, local expressions that transform appropriately) as mappings between coordinate-independent spaces.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, I have edited my question, I hope it is clearer now!